# What does the queryId and Id variable means in PlanFragmentId of Apache IoTDB and what format should they be?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now learning the configuration logic of `PlanFragmentId` in Apache IoTDB, and I noticed that there are two construction variables for `PlanFragmentId`, `queryId` and `Id`. Since these both seems to represent id information, I wonder what's the difference of the meaning of these two parameters? And also, what should the format of these two parameters should be?

I checked the official user cases, and when I try to set `queryId` to number set, seems like the error mentioned this setting is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queryId` in Apache IoTDB represents the id of the query to which the query fragment belongs. `Id` represents the id of this fragment in the query. The format of `queryId` should be `yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_index_dataNodeId`, while the value of `Id` should be an increasing integer value.